# Find missing lines by comparing two file using python re module

Tags: python

Below is my python code to find the missing lines in file_b comparing with file_a ,but issue is its showing some lines which are common in both files, along the missing lines,So please let me know your inputs to correct the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
missing = []  
found = 0  
a_file = open('a.txt','r')       
b_file = open('b.txt','r')

for line_a in a_file:  
        found = 0  
        for line_b in b_file: 
                if(re.search(line_a,line_b)): 
                found = 1  
                break           
        if (found == 0):  
                missing.append(line_a)  

a_file.close()  
b_file.close()  
print(missing)
```

Comment: Why do you want to use regex here?

Comment: Here's what I mean. if you want to see if line_a is ls in file_b, do this: `lines = b_file.readlines(); line_in_file = line_a in lines`

Comment: Just wanted to search using re.search only.

Comment: @PrashantBJ When you have a car, you insist on riding a bullock cart.

Comment: In some case I need to match a part of the string in the lines,so plan was to use re.

Comment: "In some case I need to match a part of the string in the lines": you can do that using `in` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple problems with your code. There is no need of `re` module and the `found` variable. Perhaps `re.search` is failing because `line_a` contains some special characters which are treated differently by the regex engine, e.g, a phrase like `"K.W wants some $"`.

Here's a simplified version, so that you can accomplish what you want with less complexity:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
missing = []  
with open('a.txt','r') as a_file:
    a_lines = a_file.readlines()
with open('b.txt','r') as b_file:
    b_lines = b_file.readlines()

for line_a in a_lines:   
    for line_b in b_lines: 
        if line_a in line_b:
            break
    else: 
        missing.append(line_a)  

print(missing)
```

Comment: Thanks Sam for the inputs.

Comment: `for line_a in a_lines: `
       `if line_a not in b_lines: `
            `missing.append(line_a) `

Comment: @Huang Yes that reduces some code but it would give a false negative if a `line_a` is part of a `line_b`.

Comment: I have file_a with content as a\n b\n c\n d\n e\n,and file_b with a\n b\n d\n e\n,but the code is showing missing lines as c\n d\n e\n .Also I wanted to use re because In some case I need to match a part of the string in the lines.

Comment: @PrashantBJ I've made an edit. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Sam Chats any inputs on my above comments.

Comment: @PrashantBJ you mean using `regex`? Well if you want to compare parts of both strings go for it, but if you just want to check whether `line_a` is equal to, or a part of `line_b`, the `in` operator should suffice.

Comment: @Sam Chats agreed,if want to match whole line ,your given code is fine.But in some file I just want to match a part of the line ,in such case re was option ,so used regex ,but facing issue as I said .So if you could provide your inputs for my code it would be of useful for me.

Comment: @PrashantBJ Can you provide an example case for that?

Comment: content of file_a=a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n
content of file_b=a\nb\nd\ne\n

expected is ['c\n'] is missing in file_b,
but my code is showing ['c\n', 'd\n', 'e\n'] as missing in file_b

Comment: @PrashantBJ I mean, give me an example to support your argument about using regex.

Comment: Actually I wanted to check linux kernel configs missing from kernel_b in kernel_a.So i wanted to use regex ,as it would be useful in searching a part of the line.below example will give clearer idea of my requirement. 
  
ex :  
if file_a content is as below:  
abc\n
def 123\n
ghi\n
jkl\n
mno\n

if file_b content is as below:
abc\n
def\n
jkl\n
mno\n

then comparing 2 files should show missing in file_b as:
ghi\n

Comment: I have tried your code with .readline() but ,its not exatly matching my requirement as said in my previous comment .ex if file_a content is as below: abc\n def 123\n ghi\n jkl\n mno\n if file_b content is as below: abc\n def\n jkl\n mno\n then comparing 2 files should show missing in file_b as: ghi\n

Comment: @PrashantBJ What output are you getting?

Comment: With above example of file_a ,file_b content ,your code gives missing as ['def 123\n', 'ghi\n'],but as I said my requirement is to show missing as [ 'ghi\n']  using regex.